# Fetching the first few characters of a column from a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which contains some data, here I will put some data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CgqL.jpg)

- I need to fetch the first two characters from the 'ID' column as an output, where the Quantity = 10 and Max value is   greater than 40(which we can fetch from the first two characters from 'Max value' column)

So, the output should be,

```
02
04
```

I have tried these solutions so far,

**code:**

```
var1 = data.loc[{data["Quantity"] == 10) & (data["Max value"].str[:2] == 40)]

var2 = (var1["ID"].str[:2])

print(var2)
```

**output:**

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ID, Quantity, Max value]
Index: []
```

- I thought this happened because the column name contains space character so, Other method,

**code:**

```
var1 = data.loc[(data.Quantity == 10) & (data.Max value.str[:2] > 40)].ID.str[:2]

var2 = (var1.ID.str[:2])

print(var2)
```

**output:**

```
same output
```

- Let's change the column name, method 3,

**code:**

```
data.rename(columns = {'Max value':'MaxValue'}, inplace = True)

var1 = data.loc[(data["Quantity"] == 10) & (data["Max value"].str[:2] > 40)]

var2 = (var1["ID"].str[:2])

print(var2)
```

**output:**

```
Series([], Name: ID, dtype: object)
```

- The data exists but nothing is showing up, by the way I have tried the same codes without ".loc".
- Any thoughts?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'format'? could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: Meaning, use ``` liberally~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the job:

```
df = pd.read_csv(***csv file path***)

df["Max value num"] = [int(max_val[:2]) for max_val in df["Max value"]]
desired_data = df[(df["Quantity"] == 10) & (df["Max value num"] >= 40)]
desired_data = [id[:2] for id in desired_data["ID"]]
```

This stores the first 2 characters in a list.

---

If you want to print them out like `02 04`, then use this,

```
df = pd.read_csv(***csv file path***)

df["Max value num"] = [int(max_val[:2]) for max_val in df["Max value"]]
desired_data = df[(df["Quantity"] == 10) & (df["Max value num"] >= 40)]

output = ""
for id in desired_data["ID"]:
  output += f"{id[:2]} "

output.strip(" ")
```

---

For both the codes above, I have added a `Max value num` column that stores the numeric part of the values in `Max value`.

Comment: This is perfect but the other condition is that the first two characters from the column 'Max value' should be greater than 40, the code you shared just shows one condition only, the problem occurs when I try to fetch the first two characters from the 'Max value' column.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope this works.